# How can I get x such that $x^T Ax<0$ for this given A?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 6 \\ 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$ then how can I find an X such that $X^TAX<0$ ? I found the eigen values $6\pm\sqrt{37}$ and A is not positive definite. I can't think what to do?help me... regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try $x = (1, a)^\top$ for suitably chosen $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The upshot of the procedure below is this: given real numbers $r,s,t > 0$ and symmetric matrix
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
r & s \\
s & t
\end{array}
\right)
$$ 
with **negative** determinant $rt-s^2,$ we can just take
$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
-s  \\
r 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
to get
$$ X^T A X = r(rt-s^2) < 0. $$
We could also take
$$
Y =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
-t  \\
s 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
to get
$$ Y^T A Y = t(rt-s^2) < 0. $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

ORIGINAL: It is not strictly necessary to deal with the eigenvalues when dealing with a symmetric matrix: one may find a **congruent** diagonal matrix, that is some nonsingular $P$ such that $P^T A P = D$ is diagonal. By Sylvester's law of Inertia, one of the diagonal elements will be negative, although it need not be an eigenvalue. It will then be obvious how to choose a column vector $y$ such that $y^T D y < 0.$ However, this means 
$$ 0 > y^T D y = y^T P^T A P y = (Py)^T A (Py).  $$
Taking $x=Py$ then gives $x^T A x < 0.$

$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -\frac{6}{5} \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
works. The outcome is $P^T A P = D$ with
$$
D =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
5 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{5}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

People do not seem to be familiar with this sort of thing. One place to read about it is [TREIL, Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/book.pdf). In Chapter 7, Section 2.2 is called Non-orthogonal diagonalization. Section 2.2.1 is called Diagonalization by completion of squares. The way I have shown is section 2.2.2, called ***Diagonalization using row/column operations***. This part has page numbers 202-205, but the pdf thinks they are pages 212-215, which is what the printer needed to know.

There is also a description (different book) of how to do it as an algorithm at   [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you know how to calculate an eigenvector assosciated with a given eigenvalues, then you're done, since

$$x^TAx = \lambda x^Tx = \lambda ||x||^2$$

which clearly has the same sign of $\lambda$